# How to link button to another html file (in HTML)

Tags: html

I am trying to make a button, which when clicked show an other html document.
But, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried till now

Comment: Are you looking for an HTML Button that works like a link ? Something like https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link.html

Comment: Are you trying to submit a form? Or simply you want to redirect to another page on button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an onclick event to the button:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'anotherfile.html';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>
```

or you should do like that:

```
<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "anotherfile.html";
    };
</script>
```

More Suggestions:

```
<a href='anotherfile.html'>Click here</a>
```